# Alias the fields returned from a mongodb insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, alias

I understand how to alias the names of fields returned from a request to mongodb using `collection.aggregate`, but I have not found a way of doing the same for other actions. I'm using node with the official mongodb driver.

Here is my aggregate function that works as intended when I'm finding data:

```
 return this.aggregate([
    { $match: data },
    {
      $project: {
        name: `$${namespace}-name`,
        environmentId: `$${namespace}-environmentId`,
        value: `$${namespace}-value`,
        serviceId: `$${namespace}-serviceId`
      }
    }
  ]).toArray()
```

How do I do alias the same fields so that when I have inserted, updated or deleted a document?
Currently, I am able to omit fields, but not alias them. Here is the logic I have for inserting a document:
`let data = await this.insert(validatedData, {projection: {namespace: 0}})`

Although an insert with the mongodb driver results in a `insertWriteOpResult`, it also returns an `ops` property with an array of all the documents that the user tried to insert. Is there a way of changing the fields in that array? This is because I am adding the namespace programmatically, and the requestor doesn't need to see the namespace. As far as they are concerned, `configuration-name` should just be `name` etc.

Comment: Result of write operations is [insertWriteOpResult](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpResult), not an inserted/updated document if you are using "the official mongodb driver" alone. Please review your question, as it is not quite clear what you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex, I have amended the question. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is even a good idea. Trying to limit the collections (due to cost) and so trying to implement some sort of namespacing functionality.

Comment: The second argument of [insert](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#insert) is `options` which has no  projection field to start with. Generally speaking only aggregation allows you to modify field names (if it is what you name *aliasing*) of the returned documents. I wont pretend I fully understand the question, but hope it helps.